# Why won't my classic ASP page run in the root of my ASP.NET app?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

Here's my situation - I've had an ASP.NET application running in production for a long time now (Framework 2.0) and recently migrated from one root directory to another by switching the app's home path in IIS.  Everything is running just fine, except any classic .asp scripts.  When you hit them with a browser, they start to download like a standard text file.

The application config has not been changed, just the root home directory.  Also, I have other applications on the same machine that do allow .asp to execute within them.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have the folks at serverfault help you.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem running them side by side (though crossover is essentially impossible) so it sounds like IIS is not configured to handle classic ASP requests. Check your IIS config (iirc, web service extensions > ASP > Checkbox) is set appropriately.

If that fails can you recreate the one part as a virtual directory with it's own config within the site?

Comment: Thanks - I'm not looking for crossover.  This was all previously running just fine.  As I mentioned,  I just pointed the application home directory to a different location on the server (peer directory to the original) and everything works fine (asp.net, etc.) except the classic asp scripts.

Also, I've successfully created a virtual directory in a different location that executes asp scripts from below the directory.  BUT, this is a legacy app with some legacy clients pointing to a script at the web root.  Honestly, I can repoint everyone but would like to know what the real problem is.

Comment: Oh, and within IIS > Web Service Extensions > Active Server Pages has always been allowed.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is your ASP.Net application extension is either not mapped, or mapped to a text-handling executable.

What's your ASP.Net app extension? .aspx? Get properties of your application in the IIS admin tool, click Virtual Directory, Configuration. Look at the handler for your extension, it should be aspnet_isapi.dll.

Comment: ASP.NET works fine - I'm having issues with a previously working classic asp script.

Comment: What's your classic ASP extension? .asp? Check that the handler for that is (I think) asp.dll